# Feed Forward Neural Network Matlab OCR

Tags: matlab, neural-network, ocr, feed-forward

I'm trying to create an ocr using matlab newff 
with images of characters size(32*32)

```
net = newff([0 255],[10 26],{'logsig' 'logsig'},'traingdx');
```

using P as an input matrix 
and T as an target T=eye(26,26);

```
net = train(net, P, T);
```

but i get this error 
Input data size does not match net.inputs{1}.size.
how should the code be to let it works ?

Answer (score 0):

Your input data P should have the same size than your target T. In your example. P should be a (26 x input_number) array data.